# vscode - change highlight color of current file

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

How can I add a custom style for the background of the opened file (the pale-grey behind **fetch.js**):

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `list.inactiveSelectionBackground` theme setting. You can set this using [`workbench.colorCustomizations`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme)

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "list.inactiveSelectionBackground": "#f0f"
}
```

[image]

This color used used when the explorer is not focused. Use `list.activeSelectionBackground` for when the explorer is focused

Comment: Of course it's **inactive** ... Thank you! No more close staring at the screen.

Comment: By doing cmd+shift+p -> Preferences: Open Settings (JSON), I did:

    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "list.inactiveSelectionBackground": "#1e7e1e",
        "tab.activeBackground": "#1e7e1e",
    }
worked great

Answer (score 8):

To highlight the current file **tab on top** -

Under Settings --> "*workbench.colorCustomizations*", add some colors to the tab border and/or to the tab background:

```
"tab.activeBorder": "#ff0000",
"tab.unfocusedActiveBorder": "#000000",
"tab.activeBackground": "#4a4a75",
"tab.unfocusedactiveBackground": "#000000"
```

Comment: Great, how to modify the color of the tab text/title?

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can find the solution to this problem right here:

[Visual Studio - Current file in Solution Explorer - Make it darker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671074/visual-studio-current-file-in-solution-explorer-make-it-darker)

Comment: That link is about regular Visual Studio, not VS Code